# Boot Problem in Asus EEE PC 1015CX

Tags: boot, 12.10, asus

I am a newbie to Linux world, although I have previously worked on Ubuntu 11.04 for daily use (Net Access and simple recordings using Audacity). I am not sure, at what level I stand as a newbie.

I bought this Asus Eee PC two days back. The model is Asus 1015CX. See the specs [here](http://www.flipkart.com/asus-1015cx-blk011w-laptop-2nd-gen-atom-dual-core-1gb-320gb-linux/p/itmd8qu4quzu8srr).

I created a Live USB to install 12.10. The USB booted fine. When I clicked "Try Ubuntu" option, it showed me a black screen with a cursor blinking. I waited for 15 minutes and had to restart using the power button. On clicking the "Install Ubuntu" button, the install process went seamlessly. [I have a Windows7 installed on one of the partitions]. I installed it alongside previous Windows installation.

The system was then rebooted for the first time. It showed the GRUB menu and I selected the first option Ubuntu. After showing the splash screen for a second, it began showing various messages on a black screen and then it struck on "Stopping Save kernel state message". I had to force shutdown the system using power button. Sometimes it just gives a blank screen with a cursor blinking and on pressing power button, some messages stating that acpid is doing something and stopping services pops up and the system shuts down.

I tried booting with `nomodeset` and other parameters as directed in solution to previous such problems on forums. Also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>,<kbd>F2</kbd>,<kbd>F3</kbd>,...,<kbd>F12</kbd> is not doing anything for me anywhere.

At installation, I checked Login automatically option. On booting into recovery several options comes up. Clicking resume just gives me a blank screen with cursor blinking. on dropping to root shell and remounting filesystem as RW, I am able to supply some command that worked for others.

- `startx` --> Several messages comes up with last one stating `Fatal error: No screen found`
- `sudo service lightdm start` --> Gives a blank screen with a cursor blinking
- `lspci | grep VGA` --> Shows some Intel Integrated Graphic... something I don't remember
- I had reconfigured `xserver-xorg`, `lightdm`, reinstalled `ubuntu-desktop`, `unity`.

What should I do..?? Will going back to 11.04 work..?? Or I should leave all hopes of running Ubuntu on my netbook.

Answer (score 1):

it appears that the graphical drivers of 1015cx doesn't support ubuntu 12.10. i had got the same command line output when tried to install one of the previous version of ubuntu.
getting back to 12.04 won't hurt at all because it's not a problem of broken packages, it's just that 12.10 is running but only in terminal and not graphically.
go for 12.04, it works fine on 1015cx.